# In CMake, can I remove a header from the dependency graph?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a generated header file that lots of source files include, and that may change when any one of those source files changes. But I don't want to recompile everything when one thing changes.

And it should be unnecessary to recompile. The changes to this generated header should make no difference to anything except the one source file that changed. So it is not actually necessary to have a dependency.

Is there a way to exclude this header file from the dependency graph, so that source files do not automatically recompile when it changes?

Comment: Why does this header include so many headers that don't matter to it?

Comment: @StephenNewell A script scrapes the source files for calls to functions of a certain kind, that do not otherwise exist, and the script generates those functions within the header. So, changes to one source file only affect the generated functions called by that source file, and not the generated functions called by other source files.

Comment: I'd suggest having your script generate separate headers for each source file it scrapes then.  It avoids a case where you really do want to recompile everything but miss it because one header got whitelisted (assuming there's even a way to whitelist a single header).

Comment: @StephenNewell Yes, that is a solution I considered, but it is somewhat annoying to have to have so many separate headers and make sure to #include each of them under a different name.

Comment: You don't need to give them different names, just put them under different directories and set the include directories accordingly

Comment: But I agree with Stephen that this isn't primarily a build system issue, but a code generator issue. This is just how headers work in C/C++. If a file includes another, then it depends on everything in the included file. You'll get accurate build system dependencies when you generate accurately separated headers

Comment: Good idea about the separate directories @AlexReinking thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.